# Python: How can I make my elif loop work?

Tags: python, for-loop

I just started making a game like thing, and for some reason, the elif loop isn't doing anything when "upgrade" is entered.

```
choclate = 0
multiplier = 1
multipliercost = 10
x = 1
while x == 1:
  if input() == (("choclate") + str(choclate+multiplier)):
    choclate = choclate+multiplier
    print("\nYou now have " + str(choclate) + " choclate.\nMultiplier Upgrade Cost: " + str(multipliercost) + " choclate\n")
  elif input() == "upgrade":
    multiplier = multiplier*2
    choclate = choclate-multipliercost
    multipliercost = multipliercost*2.5
    print("You have upgraded your multiplier to " + str(multiplier))
```

I am very new to coding, so I don't really know what to call this problem.

Comment: It works for me. Note that you must enter `upgrade` at the second prompt as you have two `input()`s (one for the `if` and one for the `elif`). I don't think that's what you had wanted though. You should assign the `input()` to a variable and check the same variable in both places.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `reply = input()`, `if reply == (("choclate" + str(choclate+multiplier)):`, and `elif reply == "upgrade":`?

Comment: BTW, `elif` is not a _"loop"_

Comment: Yes, I meant exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `input()` twice, then the user needs to key in twice in each round.
if you expect the user to key in only once, then you also need to call `input()` once in each round, and store it into a variable.

Here is the fix.

```
choclate = 0
multiplier = 1
multipliercost = 10
x = 1
while x == 1:
    # save the input into variable
    key_in = input()
    print(("choclate") + str(choclate+multiplier))
    if key_in == (("choclate") + str(choclate+multiplier)):
        choclate = choclate+multiplier
        print("\nYou now have " + str(choclate) + " choclate.\nMultiplier Upgrade Cost: " + str(multipliercost) + " choclate\n")
    elif key_in == "upgrade":
        multiplier = multiplier*2
        choclate = choclate-multipliercost
        multipliercost = multipliercost*2.5
        print("You have upgraded your multiplier to " + str(multiplier))
```

Comment: The while loop was there to make it go forever, as the purpose of the game is to get the most choclate as you can. If you can only input once, it completely breaks it.

Comment: If you add `else: print("test")` to the end, it prints test when you type upgrade, signaling that it isnt doing the elif thing.

Comment: it works well on my side for `upgrade` command. The `choclate x` command is hard to guess tho, that's why I print it as a cheat sheet.

Comment: If upgrade is working for everyone, it might just be the program thing im using to run it. I'm using repl, as I am doing this on a chromebook and I don't know of any other good coding programs.

Comment: oh, also, Arnold, you don't guess what choclatex is, you just type choclatex, with x being the amount of choclate you will have after you type it

Comment: Repl should be fine. you probably need to check it again? And the line `if (("choclate") + str(choclate+multiplier))` means you have to type exactly with `choclateX` with X is your current `choclate` + current `multiplier`. Otherwise, it falls to `else` condition.

Comment: The else condition is used to tell you when you get X wrong. I'll check it again.

Comment: sure, that'll be a very good hint. BTW, can you mark this answer as a solution if you don't mind. Thanks

Comment: Well, it isn't a solution though. It doesn't solve the problem, and just introduces more.

Comment: oh well, sorry I thought it solved the problem. very well.

Comment: I probably should have explained the game better, so that you would have a better idea of what I was going for, and how to fix it, so it's not your fault. Thank you for trying though. :)